# Grouping csv data by reading all lines

Tags: csv, c#-4.0

I am having the following content where I need to group by the quarter and display the information from quarter starting to end

```
A|Company1|2008-10-01 - 2008-12-31
A|Company1|2009-01-01 - 2009-03-31
A|Company1|2009-04-01 - 2009-06-30
A|Company1|2009-07-01 - 2009-09-30

A|Company1|2010-01-01 - 2010-03-31
A|Company2|2010-01-01 - 2010-03-31
A|Company1|2010-04-01 - 2010-06-30
A|Company2|2010-04-01 - 2010-06-30
A|Company1|2010-07-01 - 2010-09-30
A|Company2|2010-07-01 - 2010-09-30
A|Company1|2010-10-01 - 2010-12-31
A|Company2|2010-10-01 - 2010-12-31
```

What I need is

```
A|Company1|2008-10-01 - 2008-12-31
A|Company1|2009-01-01 - 2009-09-30
A|Company1|2010-01-01 - 2010-12-31
A|Company2|2010-01-01 - 2010-12-31
```

I need to display all the information between the quarters by separating the data. If multiple companies found I need to display in two rows else in 1 row all the data should be displayed. I tried some code to filter in to two list but not getting how to proceed to get the exact output

```
using (var reader = new StreamReader(@"D:\requirement.csv"))
{
   while (!reader.EndOfStream)
   {
       var line = reader.ReadLine();
       var values = line.LastIndexOf('|');
       string beforeLastIndex = line.Substring(0, values);
       listA.Add(beforeLastIndex);
       listB.Add(line.Substring(values + 1));
   }
}
```

Comment: I don't see where you're trying to filter out the data.

Comment: I am just getting last index and the remaining text to two different lists, but from there I am not getting how to proceed